# Insert a string at multiple indexes of another string. (preferably using preg_replace)

Tags: php, regex

I have a string as : `ABSOLUTEWORKLEADSTOSUCCESS`

I have another string as : `'+'`

Now how can I insert the second string at various indexes lets say (3,6,9) of the first string.

**PS: I know how to do it via substr(). What i am looking for is something using regex/preg_replace()**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I think that the solution below is stupid, but it does exactly what you ask for: inserts a plus sign at specific indexes using a regular expression and `preg_replace` function:

```
<?php

// find 3 groups: three first symbols, two after them, and two more
// find the pattern from the beginning of a string
$regex = '/^(.{3})(.{2})(.{2})/';
$str = 'ABSOLUTEWORKLEADSTOSUCCESS';

// perform a replace: use first group (3 symbols), insert a plus
// then use a second group (2 symbols) and insert another plus,
// then use a third group (2 more symbols) and insert the last plus
$out = preg_replace($regex, '$1+$2+$3+', $str);
echo $out;
```

Preview [here](https://3v4l.org/CMNH4).

Answer (score 0):

You can't insert string with preg_replace, for that you need to loop through the indexes and insert second string at specific index by using substr_rplace as follow

```
$var = 'ABSOLUTEWORKLEADSTOSUCCESS';
$indexes = array(3,6,9);
$newString = $var;

foreach($indexes as $key=>$value) {  
  $newString = substr_replace($newString, '+', $value+$key, 0) . "\n";
}
echo $newString;
```

check output here : https://eval.in/714177